# Transparent background on account pictures on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

Is it possible to use pictures with a transparent background as account pictures on Windows 8?

I've tried a PNG file but the background becomes black instead of transparent.

Comment: Some similar questions can be found here. http://www.sevenforums.com/themes-styles/222351-transparent-png-image-not-working-my-account-picture.html

Comment: That thread applies to windows7, and it suggests editing system DLLs, and it's not a fix for my problem anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not currently possible. The question also already came up on [eightforums](http://www.eightforums.com/customization/11445-win-8-does-not-support-transparent-backgrounds-account-picture.html) and on [Microsoft Anwers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/user-account-pictures-and-transparent-background/41a2a898-950e-44b6-878c-d2305ad12aca) and did not receive an answer there.

If even the Microsoft Answers site can not generate an answer after more than a year I think it is safe to say that there is currently no known way to achieve transparency for account pictures.